# jQuery anchor click, "this", "e.target" - returns url

Tags: jquery, html, click, javascript

I've switched from Mootools to jQuery, because I think it has better support. I've got HTML like that:

```
<ul class="menuHandler">
<li class="menuTreeElement activeOpt" id="menuOpt1">
<ul id="menuOpt1Content">
<li><a href="#" class="menuOpener">Opcje</a><a href="#" class="sprite menuOpener"></a></li>
<li class="submenuElement">Opcje</li>
<li class="submenuElement">Opcje</li>
<li class="submenuElement">Opcje</li>
<li class="submenuElement">Opcje</li>
<li class="submenuElement">Opcje</li>
<li class="submenuElement">Opcje</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('.menuTreeElement .submenuElement').hide();   
    $('.menuHandler li.menuElement, .menuHandler li.menuTreeElement').removeClass('activeOpt');
    $('.menuHandler li.menuElement, .menuHandler li.menuTreeElement').addClass('inactiveOpt');
    $('.menuHandler li.menuElement a.menuOpener, .menuHandler li.menuTreeElement a.menuOpener').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this);
    alert(this.id);
    alert($(this));
    alert(e.target);
    alert(e.target.id);
    alert($(e.target));     
    });
});
```

Results:

URL, Empty alert, [object Object], URL, Empty alert, [object Object]. I don't know what to do. Link if it'll help: http://misiur.com/CRP/admin/

I want to achieve that:
1. You click on a with class menuOpener
2. all li with class submenuElement inside same ul (in this case menuOpt1Content) are showing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('ul.menuHandler').delegate('a.menuOpener', 'click', function(ev){

     //prevent follow of link
     ev.preventDefault();

     //create a jquery object with the anchor element
     var $anchor = $(this);

     //get parent li with class menuTreeElement
     var $li = $anchor.closest('li');

     //get its siblings and show???
     $li.nextAll().show()


});
```

Comment: Same results. It's complicated, because I need to get this a parent's siblings.

Comment: You're wrong. Look at HTML of this menuTreeElement - first child is ul - it contains li, and in first one is a. I need to show this 2 level li siblings with class "submenuElement". Your code doesn't work

Comment: Well your question is hardly the best description in the world is it. Apologies for trying to help you out. Geeee

Comment: My english isn't the best, so I have to workaround hard words >< Sorry.

Comment: Whoa! - it worked! I dunno what I have changed, but this time it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menuTreeElement .menuOpener').click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.menuTreeElement .submenuElement').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.submenuElement').show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This binds lots of individual click events. Use .delegate to use event delegation

Comment: I thought the goal was "1. You click on a with class menuOpener 2. all li with class submenuElement inside same ul (in this case menuOpt1Content) are showing". What do you want with a URL? If you want the hash, use this.href or $(this).attr('href').