# event.target on anchors ( <a> tags ) error/bug?

Tags: jquery, events

## html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" >Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

## jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('ul').click(function(event){
        alert(event.target);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can someone punch me to the head and tell me **WHY** on earth `event.target` is giving me a `url` when I click on anchors? I'm expecting it to give me `[object HTMLAElement]`. Just like `[object HTMLLIElement]` when you click `li` element. [**sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rZ6Sd/).

---

I have read this [link, jquery-anchor-click-this-e-target-returns-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175646/jquery-anchor-click-this-e-target-returns-url), but doesn't seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is ok! It's just a representation of any link. You can still use `event.target.href` or even `event.target.id` and so on.

> Some elements, such as HTMLAnchorElement, have special toString functions that prevent you from finding their class name easily. If you type javascript:alert(document.links[0]) in the location bar, you will see the URL of the first link instead of its class name. The way to get around this problem is to use the default toString function on the object document.links[0], like so: javascript:alert(window.toString.apply(document.links[0])).

From [here](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html).

Comment: I don't know why, but even in the Webkit sources: 

`String HTMLAnchorElement::toString() const { return href().string(); }`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes across this issue try using:

```
var element = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
```